# How can I iterate through this table rows and cells and get the cell values using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to get this table cell data in to jQuery by iterating through this table's rows. How can I do this?

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table_GemList">
    <thead>
        <col style="width: 25%">
        <col style="width: 25%">
        <col style="width: 25%">
        <col style="width: 25%">
    </thead>
    <tbody id="GemListBody">
        <tr>
            <td>Oval</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>2.23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Oval</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>2.23</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: then what do you want to do.... and what have you tried

Comment: if u can juz tell me a way to get the values that would be enough.

Comment: @ShalinkaRandeniya That's not how StackOverflow works. Please familiarise yourself with the [How To Ask A Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple - you can select all the `td` with `$("#GemListBody td")` and loop through them using `.each()`, like this:

```
$("#GemListBody td").each(function(){

    var td = $(this);

    console.log( td.text() );

});
```

This will print all the `td` text into the console.

```js
$(function(){

  $("#GemListBody td").each(function(){

    var td = $(this);
  
    console.log( td.text() );

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table_GemList">
    <thead>
        <col style="width: 25%">
        <col style="width: 25%">
        <col style="width: 25%">
        <col style="width: 25%">
    </thead>
    <tbody id="GemListBody">
        <tr>
            <td>Oval</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>2.23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Oval</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>2.23</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```